# How to handle Azure Two factor Authentication in Selenium UI Test

Tags: azure, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am blocked in two factor authentication for writing Selenium Tests using chrome driver for  my website which has  Azure Active Directory Authentication(AAD).

First time when we login to our website  , it ask for Username & Password then it goes for Phone authentication but I won't be able to perform this action when running Selenium UI test cases from Azure Release pipeline(Azure DevOps).

Also I am trying to login website using Service account not any user account so Phone authentication cannot be set up for any Service account.

**Is there any way I can pass Bearer Access Token in Web Driver so that it can authenticate  the URL and load homepage? Post that we can continue writing UI test cases.**

**OR  Is there any provision to use App Client Id/ Secrets (which is registered in Azure App Service ) to pass it while loading URL in Web Driver?**

**OR any other way to authenticate it ?**

More Details :

Using Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0 version,
Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.10600 version.
Browser: Chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Operating System : Windows 10 Enterprise.